# What is the equivalent of java's 'constructor-overload' in python?

Tags: java, python

I'm currently studying Python. I was trying to write an exercise code making a 'Line'-class with different possible input-parameters and hence different constructors, as one can do in java. i.e a constructor with (point,point) objects and a constructor with (point,slope)  It works with both `__init__` methods separately, but not with both  as it does in python. Could anybody help me going with this.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def distance_to(self,p):
        return((p1.x-p.x)**2+(p1.y-p.y)**2)**(1/2)

class Line:
    def __init__(self, p1,p2):
        self.p1=p1
        self.p2=p2
    def __init__(self,p1,a):
        self.p1=p1
        self.a=a
        b=self.p1.y-a*p1.x
        p2=Point(0,b)
        self.p2=p2             
    def slope(self):
        return (p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x)
    def b_intersect(self):
        b_intersect=self.p1.y-self.slope()*p1.x
    def __str__(self):       
        b_intersect=self.p1.y-self.slope()*p1.x               
        if b_intersect>0:
            return 'y={}x+{}'.format(self.slope(),b_intersect)
        elif b_intersect<0:
            return 'y={}x{}'.format(self.slope(),b_intersect)
        elif b_intersect==0:
            return 'y={}x'.format(self.slope())
```

Comment: You can write one `__init__` method and inside that method you can check what arguments you received, and deal with them appropriately. That's a Python way of doing what you would do in Java with overloading.

Comment: `python` is `dynamic` :). You could check what you passed at runtime :). And you can pass anything :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*kwargs` in `__init__` method to check what arguments you received and act accordingly. Your code modified should look like this.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def distance_to(self,p):
        return((p1.x-p.x)**2+(p1.y-p.y)**2)**(1/2)

class Line:
    def __init__(self, p1,**kwargs):
        self.p1=p1
        if kwargs.get("p2") is not None:
            self.p2=p2
        elif kwargs.get("a")is not None:
            self.a=a
            b=self.p1.y-a*p1.x
            p2=Point(0,b)
            self.p2=p2  
        else:
           raise Exception("Did not give enough parameters")           
    def slope(self):
        return (p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x)
    def b_intersect(self):
        b_intersect=self.p1.y-self.slope()*p1.x
    def __str__(self):       
        b_intersect=self.p1.y-self.slope()*p1.x               
        if b_intersect>0:
            return 'y={}x+{}'.format(self.slope(),b_intersect)
        elif b_intersect<0:
            return 'y={}x{}'.format(self.slope(),b_intersect)
        elif b_intersect==0:
            return 'y={}x'.format(self.slope())
```

Comment: Ok, but with this don't they have to name the arguments when calling the constructor? I'm not sure this is what they meant.

Comment: Yes they need to name arguments. if you dont want persont to name the arguments, you can use *args instead of **kwargs. *args is an array of all the parameters. You need to check the type of the parameter you received to determine which path to choose.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about overloading a constuctor with another one that has the same number of parameters but with different types for the second one. At that point, like @khelwood said, wouldn't it be better to just accept a generic second argument (like `def __init__(self, p1,other)` and then determine the type of `other` to determine the logic?

Comment: Yes that is simple and convenient for this example. But if the situation demands more input parameters, the above way might become more simple and convenient.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but what you say is *not* wrong, it's just an answer to another question :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it's customary to write `__init__` as the low-level initializer, which can also double as the primary "constructor". Additional constructors are defined as class methods.

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    @classmethod
    def from_point_slope(cls, p1, a):
        b = self.p1.y - a * p1.x
        p2 = Point(0, b)
        return cls(p1, p2)

   # ...
```

Now `Line` has two constructors:

1. `Line.__new__` takes two `Point` objects. (It's rare to actually override `__new__`; the default of calling the parent's `__new__` and using `__init__` on the result is nearly always sufficient.)
2. `Line.from_point_slope` takes a `Point` object and a slope. It calculates a second point on the line from the first `Point` and the slope, then pass them to `Line.__new__` to create the new `Line`.

Both constructors use `Line.__init__` to actually set the two attributes `p1` and `p2`.

In the future, if you think of more ways to define a line (for example, as the intersection of two planes), you simply define new class methods, rather than complicating `__init__` further.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there are two rather simple ways to allow more than one construction syntax in Python.

Assuming that you are trying to mimic the following pair of constructors in Java:

```
class Line {
    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        ...
    }
    public Line(Point p1, float a) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

1. The parameter type test (for the simplest use cases):

   ```
   class Line:
       def __init__(self, p1, p2):
           if isinstance(p2, Point):
               # ok, initialize the Line object from 2 points
               ...
           else:
               slope = p2
               # ok, initialize the line object from 1 point and 1 float
               ...
   ```
2. The parameter name test for more complex use cases:

   ```
   class Line:
       def __init__(self, p1, p2=None, slope=None):
           # test whether syntax is Ok (optional)
           if (p2 is None and slope is None) or (p2 is not None and slope is not None):
               raise ValueError("Either p2 or slope must be given")
           if slope is None:
               # ok, initialize the Line object from 2 points p1 and p2
               ...
           else:
               # ok, initialize the line object from p1 and slope
               ...
   ```